# Webviewclientcrome is not working in android below 5.0 versions

Tags: android

My page getting the error Webpage not available in android below 5.0 versions..
[My page getting the error like that given below link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGMDE.png). Please suggest some more suggestions for that problem

Comment: Yes, its working above 5.0 versions but not works on below 5.0.. Is any answers for that problem

Answer (score 0):

Tested this code in android 4.4.4 . Everything is fine .

Webview ->

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.bankPage);
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
webView.loadUrl(URL);

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
    }
});
```

WebViewClient ->

```
WebViewClient webViewClient=new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
};
```